# PHP/SQL how to create table automatic

Tags: php, mysql

How do I make this code work if I save it as a `.php` file it says:
And I copied this code from my database and edited the names so I thought this code is fine.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'TABLE' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Informatica\tables\vraag2.php on line 2

```
CREATE TABLE `lotto`.`vraag4b` ( `VraagID2` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`Vraag4B` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `AntwA2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `AntwB2` 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `AntwC2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `AntwD2` VARCHAR(255) 
NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`VraagID1`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: post your `vraag2.php` code specific to the sql query

Comment: You are seeing the error because it is not valid PHP script.

Comment: This is SQL code not PHP. Use PDO or mysqli from PHP to connect with your local database.